# Can't get JQuery Draggable plugin to work?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm very new to `JQuery` and I'm trying to create a sample page using the Draggable plugin. The page loads fine, but I'm not able to drag my `<div>` tag anywhere. I've been trying to copy this [demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/). Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
         <style type="text/css">
                #draggable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em;  border: solid 1px black; cursor:pointer;}
         </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>


            <script src="scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"/>
            <script src="scripts/jquery.ui.core.js" type="text/javascript"/>
            <script src="scripts/jquery.ui.draggable.js" type="text/javascript"/>
            <script src="scripts/jquery.ui.mouse.js" type="text/javascript"/>
            <script src="scripts/jquery.ui.widget.js" type="text/javascript"/>
            <script src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.js" type="text/javascript" />

            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#draggable").draggable();
                });
            </script>


            <div class="demo" style="height: 500px; width: 500px;">
                <div id="draggable">
                    <p>Drag me around</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I'm just trying to make it so I can drag my "draggable" `<div>` around in the "demo" `<div>` around it. Can anyone see what I'm missing?

Comment: Can't see anything wrong with the code, make sure you've included jQuery UI as Scott suggested. Also check the console to make sure there are no errors in the javascript earlier in the page. Additionally if you want to constrain the dragging area of the #draggable div to it's parent then use `$("#draggable").draggable({containment: 'parent'});`

Comment: Thanks. I've added that now and it still doesn't seem to make a difference. Ultimately though, that's what I want - the dragging to be contained to it's parent `div`.

Comment: That will only work when draggable itself is working.

Comment: I know, I figured that. Just wanted to include it just in case :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you included the jQuery UI script on your page?  [Here is CDN link to the latest versions.](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/CDNjQueryUI1813.ashx)

I use the [Html5Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com) best practice of:

```
    </form>

    <!-- Javascript at the bottom for fast page loading -->

    <!-- Grab Google CDN's jQuery, with a protocol relative URL; fall back to local if necessary -->
    <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.6.1.js">\x3C/script>')</script>

    <!-- Grab Google CDN's jQuery UI, with a protocol relative URL; fall back to local if necessary -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> $.ui || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.min.js">\x3C/script>')</script>

    <!-- Scripts concatenated -->
    <script src="js/plugins.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- End scripts -->

</body>
```

Comment: I've included Jquery.js, Jquery.ui.core.js, and jquery.ui.draggable.js. Does that sound right?

Comment: @Lloyd: No, the `draggable` module relies on `core`, `widget` and `mouse` modules, they all have to be loaded. I suggest either load the whole jQuery UI, or build yourself a custom package at http://jqueryui.com/download

Comment: I don't know what files you have, but I would just reference the one's on the CDN like: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js" />`

Comment: @DarthJDG: Thanks, I've edited my post to include all of my code for this page. I've added the `widget` and `mouse` modules to be included but still with no luck. Can you see something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @Lloyd - Put the draggable.js last, not sure if it would matter or not.

Comment: The order of the includes are important, should probably be `core`, `mouse`, `widget` then `draggable`. But I would really recommend to include the whole thing either locally or from a CDN like @Scott suggested, or just build a custom package on the download page and include the main `jquery-ui.js` from the resulting (now a lot smaller) download.

Comment: @Scott, your HTMLBoilerPlate idea made it work. I must be missing some files or have them out of order. I'm going to try and build a custom package like @DarthJDG suggested and hopefully get everything I need out of that! Thanks so much for the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, here is my code that I was able to get working. I only needed to include 2 javascript files (one of which I was already including, and the other, jquery-ui.js, came from [here](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/jquery-ui.js), thanks to @Scott!). Also, @DarthJDG was correct, the order **DOES** matter. If I switch the order of the two script tags, the page breaks. I've only included the  tag as everything else remained the same. Thanks again everyone for pointing me in the right direction for this. Here is my code:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>

            <%--came from http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.1.js--%> 
            <script src="scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

            <%--came from //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/jquery-ui.js--%>
            <script src="scripts/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#draggable").draggable({ containment: 'parent' });
                });
            </script>


            <div class="demo" style="height: 500px; width: 500px;">
                <div id="draggable">
                    <p>Drag me around</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

DownLoad Complete JueryUI package from http://jqueryui.com/download which should include wizard.js,core.js,mouse.js and draggable.js and then use $(control).draggable() to make it work.