# JQuery Draggable - constrain to parent, but allow sliding under parent?

Tags: jquery, draggable, image, mask, image-clipping

I'm using the [JQuery Draggable plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/). I'm trying to create an Image Editing control where the user can move (and eventually resize) the draggable image. If you look at the [demo here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#default), you'll see that you can drag the grey box around and if it goes outside the bounds of the frame, you'll see the scroll bars appear and you can keep dragging. I'd like to achieve that same functionality without the scrollbars. You should be able to drag the image around and if the Image goes outside the bounds of the frame, it should appear to slide under the frame. The frame shouldn't get bigger, or have scrollbars appear. I would think this should be possible, but I haven't found a way to do so with the documentation I found. Here is my code:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #draggable { width: 400px; height: 300px; cursor:pointer;}
        #container{overflow:hidden; height: 500px; width: 500px; border: solid 1px black;}
        #slider{margin: 10px; border: solid 1px black; height: 300px; vertical-align:middle;}
    </style>

      <%--came from http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.1.js--%>
    <script src="scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <%--came from //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/jquery-ui.js--%>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function() {
              $("#draggable").draggable({ opacity: 0.35 }); //, helper: 'original', containment: 'parent'
          });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <img  id="draggable" src="images/96.jpg" width="400px" height="300px" alt="Click this image to drag it around" />
    </div>
</body>
```

**Question**: How can I make the draggable `<img>` appear to slide under the parent `<div>` while dragging - but without scrollbars appearing?

**UPDATE**: The more I think about this the more I think I should re-word my question. What I'm really wanting to do is make my parent `<div>` tag like a mask/clipping path around my draggable `<img>`. The image inside could actually be larger than the `<div>` but only what's in the `<div>` will be visible. You should be able to drag the `<img>` around inside the `<div>` as you please.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've tried changing the `z-index` on the parent `<div>` and the `<img>` itself. Didn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***[@bOkeifus is right. Check out this working jsFiddle demo:](http://jsfiddle.net/DotNetScott/dN2ZF/)***

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#draggable").draggable({ opacity: 0.35 });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <img id="draggable" 
         alt="Click this image to drag it around"             
         src="http://gallery.photo.net/photo/12355172-md.jpg" 
         width="400px"
         height="300px" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container { 
    overflow: hidden; 
    height: 500px; 
    width: 500px; 
    border: solid 1px black;
}
```

Comment: I've updated again to include my entire `<body>`. It still lets me drag the image outside of the `<div>` container. Can you see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Wrap your styles and scripts with `<head></head>`.

Comment: If that doesn't fix it, create a [jsFiddle](http://jsFiddle.net) that reproduces your error.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Updated again. Same thing.

Comment: I'm wondering if my jquery version is the problem? in the JSFiddle example, using 1.5.2 seems to work but 1.6 does not. I'll try switching my versions in code.

Comment: Try adding `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.13/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />` to your head section.

Comment: I did 1.8.13, but you will have to do 1.8.12 since that's the jQuery UI version you are using.

Comment: The Jquery version didn't seem to make a difference, and @Scott, adding the new stylesheet didn't seem to make a difference either.

Comment: If you look at my jsFiddle. It's working for me.  What browser are you in so I can test that too?

Comment: GOT IT! I copied the HTML from @Scott's JSFiddle. Now I'll have to compare that to my code and figure out what the problem was. I'm guessing it was one of the referenceds JS files?

Comment: Yea ... it's possible.  I would just reference the hosted file instead of a local file.  That way you know you have everything in there and you don't have to worry about anything.  Plus, if you reference the .min version, it's so small, it doesn't matter.

Comment: On a side note, is that a good practice to reference external JS files like that? I mean, can you safely assume that it won't change and break your code? Or do they always just add new files and leave the older versions alone?

Comment: Yea, it is.  The way I showed you in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144188/cant-get-jquery-draggable-plugin-to-work is the best practice.  And yes, they will always remain the same.  Each time they release a new version, it's a new file, and the older version remains for backward compatibility.

Comment: Awesome! You've saved me again!

Comment: LoL ... glad you are all set!

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you should set:

```
overflow:hidden;
```

in your div's style. This should stop the scrollbars from appearing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That is a great idea but I think the `containment: 'parent'` is preventing overflow. Adding the `overflow:hidden;` didn't seem to make a difference. However, if I remove the containment, it allows me to drag outside of the div, with the overflow visible. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Lloyd - @bOkeifus is right. +1. You take off `containment: 'parent'` and add `overflow: hidden;` to the container and you get your achieved results. Check out my answer with the working jsFiddle demo.